# using webpack angular2-router-loader to load from javascript rather than typescript

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to use the angular2-router-loader, however, it does not allow parsing javascript files, only typescript files, hence an error "Unexpected token". Is there anyway to specify to parse javascript files instead?